# Can't pass Object via intent in Android N

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-7.0-nougat

I am having a problem passing an Object via intent in Android N. The bellow code works perfectly in Android pre-N versions, but in Android N the Object I am trying to pass it via intent is null. Can someone help me with this problem?

I have tried to pass it using bundle, and also as a byte array but the problem is the same.

Here is my code:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra(SCENARIO, Constants.SCENARIO_REMINDER_RECEIVE);
    intent.putExtra(TASK_NAME, task.getTask());
    intent.putExtra(TASK_ID, task.getId());
    intent.putExtra(TASK_MESSAGE_KEY, task.getMessageKey());
    intent.putExtra(TASK_STATUS, task.getStatus());
    intent.putExtra("Task", task);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

in the BroadcastReceiver in onReceive I get null for task:

```
     @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

     task = (Task) intent.getSerializableExtra("Task");
     requestCode = intent.getLongExtra(REQUEST_CODE, requestCode);
     Timber.d("task in onReceive: " + task);
```

Comment: have you tried adding `action`? `intent.setAction(System.currentTimeMillis());`

Comment: Why would I need the action?

Comment: because it should be always and in some cases lack of it may broke some behaviour. I met this problem few times (related with `AppWidget`, In-app opening etc.), but never in case of different OS versions. But still... if you don't really need `action` just set anything, I'm using timeStamp to differ every `Intent`. It's just a guess, so I'm commenting, not answering ;)

Comment: I've tried setting an action and the problem still occurs. Anyway thank you :)